# How to save and share pdf file, that was downloaded using url and save to cache folder of app

Tags: android, pdf, kotlin

Using the below set of code, I am trying to get the pdf file using the URL and then I need to share the file via mail or save it to the device storage.

But I'm not getting the correct syntax that will save the file as well as share it. Using this code I'm able to mail it, but I can not save it or share using the app ShareIt.

```
class PdfReaderFragment : BaseFragment(), ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, CopyAsset.Listener, DownloadFile.Listener         
{

    private var pdfViewPager: PDFViewPager? = null
    private var destinationPath: String? = null

    override fun onSuccess(url: String?, destinationPath: String?) {
        if (view != null) {
            this.destinationPath = destinationPath
            progressBar?.visibility = View.GONE
            pdfViewPager = PDFViewPager(activity, destinationPath)
            pdfPagerContainer?.addView(pdfViewPager)
            pageCountTextView?.text = 1.toString() + " of " + pdfViewPager?.adapter?.count
            pdfViewPager?.addOnPageChangeListener(this)
        }
    }

    override fun onFailure(e: Exception?) {
        if (view != null) {
            ToastClass().show(activity, " Can't Open file")
            progressBar?.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pdfreader, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setTitleAtCentre(view)

        shareImageView.setOnClickListener {
            if (destinationPath != null) {

                val file = File(destinationPath)
                val uri = context?.let { it1 ->
                    FileProvider.getUriForFile(it1, "com.app.project.fileprovider", file)
                }

                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                intent.type = "application/pdf"
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, file.name.toString())
                if (intent.resolveActivity(activity.packageManager) != null) {
                    ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity)
                        .setType("application/pdf")
                        .setStream(uri)
                        .setSubject(file.name.toString())
                        .startChooser()
                } else ToastClass().show(activity, "NOT FOUND")
            }
        }

        RemotePDFViewPager(context, arguments.getString("url"), this)
    }

    override fun success(assetName: String?, destinationPath: String) {
        progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        pdfViewPager = PDFViewPager(activity, destinationPath)
        pdfPagerContainer.addView(pdfViewPager)
        pageCountTextView.text = 1.toString() + " of " + pdfViewPager?.adapter?.count
        pdfViewPager?.addOnPageChangeListener(this)
    }

    override fun failure(e: Exception?) {
        ToastClass().show(activity, "Can't Open File")
        progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {}
    override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {}
    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
        pageCountTextView.text = (position + 1).toString() + " of " + pdfViewPager?.adapter?.count
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        if (pdfViewPager != null)
            (pdfViewPager?.adapter as PDFPagerAdapter).close()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a link which will guide you to download image
using httpurlconnection.
[Download Image In Android](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/use-httpurlconnection-to-download-file-from-an-http-url)

If you want to share something to explicitly then you may pass
the data in sharingIntent described in following link
[Sharing Content with intent](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sharing-Content-with-Intents)

Comment: I don't think it's the required solution to my question.